# Bluemix very slow to start Spring Boot application, hangs

Tags: docker, spring-boot, ibm-cloud

I am trying to deploy a simple Spring Boot application to Bluemix using Docker image.
The image is based on `dockerfile/java:oracle-java8` and runs perfectly find on my local Linux VM - it starts within 10-30 seconds.
However the Blumix container running the same image in the cloud takes more than 10 minutes to start. The Bluemix console page shows status as `Running`, but there is no progress (judging by logs) for the past 10 minutes.  I get following log (notice the time intervals) using the `sudo ice logs -o myContainer` command:

```
Target is container cloud. Invoking cloud service...

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m      [2m (v1.2.1.RELEASE)[0;39m

[2m2015-02-04 21:07:49.006[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.dash.nlpHighlight.web.App           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting App with PID 1 (/opt/highlighter/highlighter-0.0.1.jar started by root in /opt/highlighter)
[2m2015-02-04 21:07:49.057[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5aa60e57: startup date [Wed Feb 04 21:07:49 UTC 2015]; root of context hierarchy
[2m2015-02-04 21:07:52.773[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
```

Using `sudo ice inspect myContainer` i get:

```
Target is container cloud. Invoking cloud service...
{
    "Config": {
        "AttachStderr": "",
        "AttachStdin": "",
        "AttachStdout": "",
        "Cmd": [
            "date"
        ],
        "Dns": "",
        "Env": {
            "group-id": "0000",
            "space-id": "5588d535-a208-4cd2-be05-db781af48ada",
            "tagformat": "space-id group-id uuid",
            "tagseparator": "_"
        },
        "Hostname": "",
        "Image": "registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/myOrg/myImage:latest",
        "Memory": 256,
        "MemorySwap": "",
        "OpenStdin": "",
        "PortSpecs": "",
        "StdinOnce": "",
        "Tty": "",
        "User": "",
        "VCPU": 1,
        "Volumes": [],
        "VolumesFrom": "",
        "WorkingDir": ""
    },
    "Created": "2015-02-04T21:35:17Z",
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": "null",
        "CapAdd": [],
        "CapDrop": [],
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "Links": [],
        "LxcConf": [],
        "PortBindings": {},
        "Privileged": "false",
        "PublishAllPorts": "false"
    },
    "HostId": "c4cc40876ba4db63069eb35d061670783146287b3d9ca5155dedf1be",
    "Human_id": "myContainer",
    "Id": "fa15e14d-ffe2-4621-b81a-579a60b52936",
    "Image": "ecbb9431-822e-4e74-8a04-5b942743a42c",
    "Name": "myContainer",
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "Gateway": "",
        "IpAddress": "172.16.46.71",
        "IpPrefixLen": 0,
        "PortMapping": "null",
        "PublicIpAddress": "129.41.249.63"
    },
    "Path": "date",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/etc/resolv.conf",
    "State": {
        "ExitCode": "",
        "Ghost": "",
        "Pid": "",
        "Running": "true",
        "StartedAt": "",
        "Status": "Running"
    },
    "Volumes": []
}
```

Initially I started the container using `ice run myContainer myImage`. I stopped and started the container, but it did not solve the problem.

Here are the contents of the Docker file:

```
FROM dockerfile/java:oracle-java8
ADD myJar-0.0.1.jar /opt/myFolder/
ADD application.properties /opt/myFolder/
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /opt/myFolder/
CMD ["java", "-jar", "-Xmx1500m", "myJar-0.0.1.jar"]
```

Comment: Could you post a link to your docker file debugging help?

Comment: Can you capture a thread dump when it's hung?

Comment: What is "docker file debugging help"? And how do I "capture a thread dump"?

Comment: Did you modify the dockerfile/java:oracle-java8 image or are you using it un-modified?

Comment: @JeffSloyer  I am using unmodified dockerfile/java:oracle-java8 image + my runnable JAR.

Comment: Is there anything special you are doing in your jar? Is there anyway you could post it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue with binding a port to your app.

In your Dockerfile you need the following.

EXPOSE

Where port is 22, 80, 443, 9080, or 9443.

Additionally you need to define a command to start your app.

CMD["...."]

This is from step 6 from https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/Containers/index.html.

Comment: I do have "EXPOSE" and "CMD" in my docker. I will post it.

Comment: I believe there is some issue with resource allocation - my app does start asking Java for 1.5Gb RAM, which is under 2Gb that is allowed on Bluemix. However I think it just does not get that RAM.

Comment: Hmm, could you try doing something a little smaller or pair down your app a little to try to see where the issue is?

Comment: Ok, I will try it when I have time.

Comment: Hey, I am experiencing similar issue, container starts slow and then dies, with this image {https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/codeskyblue/docker-gogs/}. Another related question I have is - how can I expose port 3000? The official docs say that "The only open ports for Containers and your floating IP are: 22, 80, 443, 9080, and 9443.".

Comment: You can't expose port 3000, it needs to be either 22, 80, 443, 9080 or 9433.  Can you start your app on one of those ports?

Comment: @DaSh could you please accept an answer so we can close this out?

Comment: Well, I never got it to work really and I gave up on it. It worked on AWS. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: What was the last issue you were hitting?

Comment: The containers were just dying after starting. Running out of memory or whatever.

Comment: Did you try reducing the required memory for your container?

Comment: Jeff, i just stopped debugging this at some point. I don't have a ton of free time :)